# How to pipe from audio element stream in browser

Tags: html, websocket, html5-audio

How to pipe from audio element stream in browser

from within the browser of audio element how would I hook on its
window.stream and pipe it to a websocket?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Web Audio Context
2. Add a MediaElementAudioSourceNode
3. Add a MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode
4. Connect the source node to the destination node
5. Instantiate a MediaRecorder with the `.stream` property of the destination node.
6. Start the MediaRecorder and play some sound out of your audio node.
7. When the MediaRecorder fires its `dataavailable` events, take the resulting data and write it to your web socket.